# PHP cannot output images

Tags: php, image, output

```
<?php
  ob_clean();
  header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
  $file = '111111-11111.jpg';
  $handle = fopen($file, "r");
  echo file_get_contents($file);
?>
```

At one point my php webpage stopped displaying all and any images I had successfully uploaded to MySQL database. I wanted to get down to the roots of this problem and see if it could output a .jpg image stored on HDD and all I get is the same output as when I'm trying access this image from database:

The image [...] could not be displayed because it contains errors.

The image location is correct, there are no whitespaces before header, the output buffer has been cleaned. I have spent days on google searching for the answer, but without luck.

I am quite new to PHP so if you can help, please be as descriptive as you can be, so I could understand.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the error_log for any PHP errors, perhaps permission based? Also, you don't need the `$handle = ...` line as you are not using it

Comment: Check the raw output from the page. It might have some errors in the stream. Use `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` to disable that.

Comment: Also, you don't need to `fopen()` the file before using `file_get_contents()`.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that the file you are trying to output is in the correct path (from the code, the same as the PHP script) and that you have the read permissions on the file.

```
$file = '111111-11111.jpg';
$type = 'image/jpeg';
header('Content-Type:'.$type);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

Comment: To be noted: The order of instructions was to be changed and this one looks better (filesize calculation was being done before setting the path to the file)

Comment: Tried your suggested code, and it's still giving me the same error. The file really is there, under the same name and I DO have the necessary permissions, but It is still not giving me anything.

Comment: The image [...] could not be displayed because it contains errors.<<< this error, if you can call it an error. Everything I do leads back to this.

Comment: Try another image and let me know.

Comment: @Napolux Okay, so maybe I am dumb... Just tried to open windows' sample .jpg picture, and it worked. That leaves me with a question - why is it giving me error when this picture is shown once I put it on a database?